# SpriteKit Transition or move between two Scenes, creating with GameScene?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, scenekit

I have a SpriteKit app. I would like to simply switch from one view class to another. In this case, I would like to just switch from one screen to another screen in the app, so that you can have different things on display that were triggered from a button press or some other logic in the code.

I am having trouble creating the second GameScene, as I get some errors. Could someone provide an example of just switching from one scene to another.
Here is some code I attempted to get working:

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
    var player = SKSpriteNode()
    var ground2 = SKSpriteNode()
// The main scene that loads just fine and runs. However I want to transition to another scene, the desert scene. With logic from here to there.
}

class DesertScene : SKScene {
    // inserting my variables, my logic, CGPoints, you get it.
}
func goToScene(newScene: SceneType) {
    var sceneToLoad:SKScene?

    switch newScene {
    case SceneType.GameScene:
        sceneToLoad = GameScene(fileNamed: "GameScene.swift")
    case SceneType.TheWoods:
        sceneToLoad = TheWoods(fileNamed: "TheWoods")
    case SceneType.DesertScene:
        sceneToLoad = DesertScene(fileNamed:"DesertScene")
    }
}
```

I was not really sure how to transition between either SKS files or even if I should create a new swift file, and have it access GameScene.swift

Answer (score 0):

If you try to start a new SKScene using the same view controller, the entire previous SKS will be leaked. I've encountered this issue before.

In your case, you want to start a new GameScene. I'd suggest you creating a new swift file and initialize that gamescene, as you've suggested in your question.

Check out my [post](https://techwithkevin.com/KVBlog/memory.html) here, which explains why a new SKScene shouldn't be initialized within the same VC.